# MS Access workaround for ORA-01461 - *without* modifying table data types

Tags: oracle, ms-access, type-conversion

I'm trying to update an oracle table with the LONG data type using an MS Access update query - and keep getting the infamous ORA-01461 error message (can only bind long data to long data type fields).

I know that the solution is to stop using LONG and start using CLOB, etc - but I don't have access to any of that side of things so that's not an option.  I've contacted the relevant people in the organisation multiple times to no avail (the database is the usual hack job thrown together by someone who doesn't work here anymore, and IT won't touch it with a 10 foot pole), so we have to assume this field will be LONG for the foreseeable future.

What I'm wondering is can I use a hideous combination of nested functions in the update query to bypass the issue?

I know that's an objectively poor solution.
I know that changing the data type is better (see above)
I know that asking for in-house help is better (see above)

Does anyone have any other suggestions? Besides changing job :)

Comment: No idea of what you're doing exactly but `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(column_name_here, 4000, 1)` will convert CLOB data to good old VARCHAR2.

Comment: ... truncating it to 4000 characters in the process (obviously).

Comment: A **Pass-Through query** can do anything you could do directly on the server.